# Hide image when the src is unknown

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide images without the src in WordPress.

Following is the image code displaying on the front end

`<img src="[custom-gallery-image-01]" class="galimage" height="300" width="580"/`>

JS used to hide the image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".galimage").each(function() {
        var atr = $(this).attr("src"); 
        if(atr == "") {
            $(this).addClass("hidegalimage");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidegalimage");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.hidegalimage {
display:none;
}
```

But I can still see the broken image icon & an image border. View [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vrcv9kk/7/). Can someone fix my issue or give me a suggestion how to hide the image?

Many thanks

Comment: `disply:none;` Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: My bad, I fixed it in the JSFiddle, but it still shows the broken image

Comment: Assuming the `[custom-gallery-image-01]` shortcode gets replaced by an empty string if no image is found, then your code does work: https://jsfiddle.net/ukc78mrm/

Comment: In your code you're looking to see if src equals a blank string. But in your image tag your string is set to a literal string of [custom-gallery-image-01]. When the function runs it's not setting your class because src isn't empty.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thanks!

Comment: @bnjmn.myers Thanks, I didn't know that..

Comment: Don't mention it :)

Comment: Glad to help be of assistance. Happy coding!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much more elegant to use CSS instead, no Javascript required, assuming the bad `src`s <strike>start with `[` as in your HTML:</strike> are empty strings:

```css
.galimage[src=""] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3559198b8028bd3d8e82c00d16d2e10?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="galimage" height="300" width="580"/>
<img src="" class="galimage" height="300" width="580"/>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b3559198b8028bd3d8e82c00d16d2e10?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="galimage" height="300" width="580"/>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks HEAPS! This worked like a charm.. When I inspected the element without the src, it showed src(unknown). But after adding your CSS, works great.

Comment: @cale_b Thanks, I didn't think the issue that way either

Comment: Thanks heaps for your time, efforts & knowledge guys!

Answer (score 1):

**Using jquery**

```
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Or

```
$("img").error(function (){ 
    $(this).hide();
    // or $(this).css({'display','none'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- no need for CSS alternative

You can use this but this is not hidding its removing from the page at all (DOM):

```
<img id='any' src="https://invalid.com" onerror="document.getElementById(this.id).remove()" >
```